# Timeout::Error isn't rescuing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, timeout

I am still new with Ruby and for the first time I'm trying to use Timeout for some HTTP functions but clearly I'm missing the mark somewhere.  My code is below but it's not working.  Instead, it raises the following exception:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': execution expired (Timeout::Error)
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense to me since the part of the code it's timing out on is wrapped in a begin/rescue/end block and specifically rescues Timeout::Error.  Am I doing something wrong, or something that isn't supported in Ruby?

```
    retries = 10
    Timeout::timeout(5) do
      begin
        File.open("#{$temp}\\http.log", 'w') { |f|
          http.request(request) do |str|
            f.write str.body
          end
        }
      rescue Timeout::Error
        if retries > 0
          print "Timeout - Retrying..."
          retries -= 1
          retry
        else
          puts "ERROR: Not responding after 10 retries!  Giving up!")
          exit
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 22):

The `Timeout::Error` is getting raised in the call to `Timeout::timeout`, so you need to put that inside the `begin` block:

```
retries = 10
begin
  Timeout::timeout(5) do
    File.open("#{$temp}\\http.log", 'w') do |f|
      http.request(request) do |str|
        f.write str.body
      end
    end
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  if retries > 0
    print "Timeout - Retrying..."
    retries -= 1
    retry
  else
    puts "ERROR: Not responding after 10 retries!  Giving up!")
    exit
  end
end
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Wow, thank you for the quick reply.  I figured that was something dumb, but I'm still getting used to Ruby and help from places like this help me a lot.  Thank you!

Comment: Amazing! Totally loved it.

Answer (score 3):

Use retryable to make this simple

https://github.com/nfedyashev/retryable#readme

```
require "open-uri"

retryable(:tries => 3, :on => OpenURI::HTTPError) do
  xml = open("http://example.com/test.xml").read
end
```